# Gitlab: Issue Weight not settable after upgrade to 9.0.2

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I've learned yesterday in their webcast that Gitlab 9.0.2 will support issue weights for instance for sprint planning purposes and also found related screenshots out there. However, after upgrading our local Gitlab installation from 8.x (can remember the exact version) to 9.0.2 on a Debian system (Omnibus installation) I didn't get the issue weights.
Is it necessary to enable something on system or project base? Unfortunately, Gitlab documentation is not very helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

Issue weights are only available in the enterprise editions of GitLab, so if you use the community edition, you are out of luck.

Check the comparison chart out [here.](https://about.gitlab.com/products/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create labels "Weight 1", "Weight 2", etc., works even better than weight, add them in the group to be available for all projects, after that, in the project you add as priority labels and sort in priority you want. You can filter and sort labels equal weight (: